# Having Trouble When I Fetched Data From Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I fetched data from Firebase database, I get only single value. But I want to get all the entire record of firebase realtime database.

Here is my Java code:

```
mref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        HashMap<String, Object> users = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        listusers.add(users.get("FirstName").toString());
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listusers);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

How to overcome this situation?

Comment: A lot depends on your actual data (please add a relevant snippet of that to your question). But you may be looking for `ValueEventListener`.

Comment: any sample example which can help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to wire up a `ListAdapter` to a collection of users that is stored in Firebase.

I **highly** recommend that you study the [Firebase AndroidChat sample application](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat) as it covers most things you'll run into. Amongst others that sample app has a great utility class `FirebaseListAdapter` that does exactly what you need here: it adapts a Firebase collection for use with an Android `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try code like this...

```
mref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        HashMap<String, Object> users = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.child("FirtsName").getValue();
        listusers.add(users.toString());
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listusers);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Line number-5 fetch only value "FirstName" child and add into List